# How to download a csv file from Google Drive to show the content in a mobile app

Tags: ionic-framework, google-drive-api, google-oauth, ionic4, google-drive-android-api

I am totally new in mobile app development and consequently very confused about how to get going (independent from how much I have read Google Drive API documentation over and over again.)

The way I would like to implement my (initially "android") mobile app (which I will develop by using ionic):

- I will have a Google Drive account where I will have 1 CSV file. I will periodically renew the content of the file in the background (possibly twice a week).
- The mobile app that I will develop will just retrieve the file from Google Drive, process the content and show it to the user in a more readable (easy to understand) format.
- My app will **not** upload any data/file from the user device to the Google Drive. The app will only retrieve a file from Google Drive to show the content to the user.

**Question 1)** Does this approach make sense? I ideally would like to eliminate the work for back-end development. Or would you suggest another approach to do the same thing (with or without Google Drive)?

**Question 2)** The authorization process looks quite confusing to me as it is explained in Google's documentation. I could not find relevant information only addressing the scenario I have in my use case. Requirements: The mobile apps can fetch the corresponding file (or the content of it) and process it to show to the end user, but mobile apps (or any other client) may not update/edit/delete the file, cannot add a new file either. The only purpose of using the Google Drive will be to enable the mobile app fetching the data that will be shown to the user. How can this problem be solved by using Google's OAuth framework? A step by step action plan would really be appreciated.

### **ADDENDUM**

You are also welcome to share your view if I should instead consider using Firebase for my problem, which I guess will be more costly.

Comment: is the data private? You can just set up a public share url for the asset on Google Drive and just use that direct url instead of setting up the Google Drive API.

Comment: That is an option. But I would like the csv file to be accessible only to my mobile app. With other words, I don't want it to be accessible to other people not using the mobile app. @rtpHarry, any comments based on these requirements?

Comment: ok yes you need the api then or firebase could be a reasonable option. They give quite large free tier. Are you expecting a huge amount of users? I tried searching and Google Drive + Ionic 4 seems to be not embraced by the community much. Firebase tutorials however, are everywhere, and setting up email / pass login is easy.

Comment: I've kept investigating at the same time. It really looks like Firebase is the way to go.  There is a lot more information/tutorial on how to use Ionic with Firebase. I don't know how big the app will be in terms of number of users. If it gets big enough, I assume that the income of it will pay off the cost of Firebase. There are some other costs around it so one of my intentions was to minimize the cost by using the Google Drive instead. But seemingly, Firebase will make the life much easier from many aspects. Thanks, @rtpHarry! Anyone else having another opinion is welcome to comment/answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on discussing the requirements with you, I would recommend against trying to do this with Google Drive API.

There are no tutorials out there for Ionic 4 + Google Drive API, and only a few for older versions. It will be an uphill struggle to create a solution that isn't going to scale well.

Instead you should start looking into using Firebase.

There are lots of tutorials which show you the basics: setting up a login system, and reading some data from the database.

The free limits are quite generous.

You can implement caching into your app so that you store a copy of the data on the device, and only refresh it either weekly, or more advanced, put a second table in that records the last updated date for the main table.

Firebase charges by reads so if you can set it up so that you only read one record (last updated) instead of downloading the whole database every time, then you can stretch your free tier a lot further.

If you do outgrow the free tier and the app is not generating enough to cover the costs then you have the option of investing time instead of money. There are guides in the docs about exporting the users and they provide tools so that the passwords can be put into another system without requiring the users to reset their passwords. The database can be similarly exported.

Comment: thanks a lot for the very insightful answer! It makes totally sense.